# Get object value by JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

Okay, I have this code

```
localStorage.lang = "th"
var k;
switch(localStorage.lang){
    case "th":
        k = "NameThai";
        break;
    case "en":
        k = "NameEnglish";
        break;
}

$("#test").html(some.object.properties.k);
```

If `localStorage.lang` is `'th'`, I expect `k` to be `"NameThai"`, and `$("test").html` is set to `some.object.properties.NameThai`

And if If `localStorage.lang` is `'en'`, I expect `k` to be `"NameEnglish"`, and `$("test").html` is set to `some.object.properties.NameEnglish`

I know my code is wrong, since `k` in `$("#test").html(some.object.properties.k);` does not refer to variable `k`, but refers to object `k` instead.

Are there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Try some.object.properties[k]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes use bracket notation, like this..

```
$("#test").html(some.object.properties[k]);
```

Answer (score 2):

This will do the trick:

```
  $("#test").html(some.object.properties[k]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$("#test").html(some.object.properties[k]);
```